# Curl or HTTP Client - Get content before redirecting

Tags: php, curl

Using Symfony, I want to get the content of a web page using PHP.

I tried to use Symfony HTTP Client :

```
        $client = new NativeHttpClient();

        $response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
            'max_redirects' => 0,
        ]);

        $content = $response->getContent();
```

But I have an error because I have a redirection. I tried using classic CuRL PHP using this option :

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

But I can't get the content, it return `true`.

So for now, only `file_get_contents()` works, but I need to pass Cookie file and it's not really POO..

Is there a way to get the content before a 301 redirect using CuRL ?

Comment: You didn't show us your curl-using code so we can't point out the mistake. It is easily done with curl.